# Type casting at once python

Tags: python, types, casting

How can I do this better?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

text = "50:0.0"

(string, floating) = text.split(':')

floating = float(floating)
```

Particularly the casting part of it. Is it possible to include casting part within the second line of the code?

Comment: There is a parse lib: https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse

Comment: If it was in C I would do this sscanf(str, "%s %f", string, &floating). something similar in one line i was after in python :)

Answer (score 0):

Not in any way that is simpler than what you already have:

```
string, floating = (lambda (x, y): (x, float(y)))(text.split(':'))
```

Comment: Pretty neat. Thanks very much for that :)